# Access Elements in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following item template (I tried to strip all the non relevant stuff):

```
<s:SurfaceWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type s:SurfaceListBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:myClass}"> //my own class
                    <s:SurfaceButton>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}">        //name is a string in my own class
//and close all the tags
```

The idea is that my listbox will contain buttons which are displaying some words on it.

Further down, I have a `SurfaceListBox` using the above resource. I add in an item by:

```
myListBox.Items.Add(new myClass("My Name"));
```

And it would add a button to the listbox nicely, with the button displaying "My Name".

Now I need to change "My Name" to another string.

How do I access that `TextBlock`?

I have tried googling but the solutions to access items in `DataTemplate` they all require `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount` via `FindVisualChild`, which returns 0 for me so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple and right way to achieve this is using `DataBinding`.

Update the TextBlock XAML so that TextBlock can update itself whenever backend `name` property changes

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

In you `myClass` implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). Then whenever you wish to change the text call `PropertyChanged` event.

```
public name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        PropertyChanged("name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! The problem actually expands further than that. I also need to change the `FontStyle` for some of the `TextBlock` in the buttons to Italic or Oblique. Hence I'm hoping to be able to access the `TextBlock` directly, or is it possible to also change the `FontStyle` using your method?

Comment: @DarrenNg You can change every property that is a Dependency property using Binding which includes `FontStyle`